# Debugging STM32 Cortex-M4, running debugger causes hard fault

Tags: c, debugging, arm, gdb

I'm trying to debug some firmware I'm developing on an STM32 Nucleo-64 dev board which has an STM32L412RBT6 Cortex-M4 MCU, and I've been running into a very weird error. Basically, when I try to debug, I end up getting a hard fault on one specific instruction (details below). The odd thing is that this only happens when I'm debugging. If I reset the MCU and let it run without the debugger, it executes the line fine and moves on with the rest of the code.

My setup:
- Using the onboard ST-Link debugger on the Nucleo board
- STM32CubeIDE environment
- GDB debugger

The debugging process seems to be working fine other than this hard fault. I can start the debugger, step through some commands, see changes in variables in my watch list, turn on/off LEDs, etc.

The line that causes the hard fault when debugging is a SPI read-write command:

```c
ret = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *) txBuffer, (uint8_t *) rxBuffer, 4, 1000);
```

And the line within the HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive() function that causes the fault is the if statement:

```c
if ((((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) >=  Timeout) && ((Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)))
       || (Timeout == 0U))
      {
        errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
        goto error;
      }
```

I've just started working on this project and was just trying to run a quick SPI loopback test to make sure the driver was working properly. There is very little else in the project at the moment, just some initialization for the clock, GPIO, and SPI. I'm confident the code is sound, and again it is working fine when I'm not actively debugging.

I don't have any experience debugging these types of errors. After some searching, I arrived at the Cortex status registers. The Configurable Fault Status Register has a value of 0x0008 0000, which corresponds to the NOCP bit being set, indicating that a coprocessor instruction was issued but the coprocessor was disabled or not present. I'm not sure how this could be relevant, is there something I'm missing? The Hard Fault Status Register has a value of 0x0400 0000, with the FORCED bit set (meaning a configurable fault was escalated to a hard fault).

When I reset the MCU within the debug environment, it immediately goes to the hard fault handler. In that case, the Configurable Fault Status Register has a value of 0x8200, with the BFARVALID and PRECISERR bits set. With BFARVALID set, the Bus Fault Address Register holds the address that triggered the fault, and it has a value of 0x2000 a008. Here's where I get really confused, as the memory ranges for this chip are flash program memory from 0x0800 0000 to 0x0802 0000, and SRAM from 0x2000 0000 to 0x2000 a000, so the address of 0x2000 a008 is outside of either of those. I'm really stumped by this and not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: See if this thread has any useful insights: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000ADE0G2SQL/stm32f030c8tx-was-a-hard-fault-when-using-spi-hal.  Specifically, 1) byte alignment, and 2) timing

Comment: This almost certainly does not weigh into the problems you're having, but aren't the conditions in the `if` test reversed?  Unless you intentionally need to call `HAL_GetTick()` for some kind of side effect, it would make a lot more sense to put the `(Timeout == 0U)` test first: if the timeout is zero, the short-circuiting rules of C for `||` mean that the rest won't be executed at all because the full condition has been satisfied.

Comment: @SteveFriedl - I see your point, agreed that it doesn't seem related to the issue at hand, but it would make more sense to test the `(Timeout == 0U)` condition first for the reason you stated. The `HAL_GetTick()` function does not perform any calculations or update any variables, it only returns a value. Incidentally this is right from the HAL library provided by ST, not sure why they structured it that way.

Comment: @FoggyDay Thanks for the reference. I tried reworking the SPI transmit/receive code code to avoid casting unaligned byte pointers into word pointers, but that does not seem to solve the problem. I didn't follow exactly what they were referring to with the timing, but I checked through the logic of the writes to the TXFIFO and reads from the RXFIFO and everything seems consistent to me.